# 403 when trying to retrieve data via the JSON:API

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to find all taxonomy terms, where one field IS NULL via the JSON API.

So I'm testing to retrieve a node via the name and it works without any issues:

```
/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/tax?filter[title-filter][condition][path]=name&filter[title-filter][condition][operator]=%3D&filter[title-filter][condition][value]=Test
```

Then, I'm trying to use another operator on another field:

```
/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/tax?filter[tomatch][condition][path]=field_geolocation&filter[tomatch][condition][operator]=IS%20NULL
```

And I receive a respone:

> 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: /jsonapi/taxonomy_term/place?filter%5Btomatch%5D%5Bcondition%5D%5Bpath%5D=field_geolocation&filter%5Btomatch%5D%5Bcondition%5D%5Boperator%5D=IS%20NULL

Just to see, whether there are any issues with the field, I'm trying via the name (and once more the description) again:

```
/jsonapi/taxonomy_term/place?filter[tomatch][condition][path]=name&filter[tomatch][condition][operator]=IS%20NULL
```

And I receive the same 403.

- D10.1
- Field Permissions installed
- Special role for the API user
- Switched field permissions off for the geolocation field for testing
- Checked the JSON output of the successful response for the field name
- And Python specific, I tried the string `'IS%20NULL'` and `urllib.parse.quote("IS NULL")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try uninstalling Field Permissions and see if it works?  I just tried your code as an anonymous user on a site of mine (`?filter[tomatch][condition][path]=t.value&filter[tomatch][condition][operator]=IS%20NULL`) and it returns the null fields as expected, no error.

Comment: Still the same. I've uninstalled the module on a dev version of the site. Other requests work. Before and after uninstalling (and clearing the cache) I run into the 403.

Comment: How are you testing this?  I would try it in the browser first.  The IS NULL check on the path field should definitely work, so that's the one I would start with.  JSON:API permissions are supposed to be exactly the same as the normal Drupal permissions, so users generally should be able to access the path, and so JSON:API should allow filtering on the path.  If you're still getting a 403, it is likely that your API user does not have the correct permissions, so try giving that role more permissions in the admin UI.

Comment: Now I've tried it via frontend - logged in with the API user, edited a taxonomy term, added the lat/lon and it worked.